# Register form checking if form is filled in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have created a registration form and I am trying to do a check to see if all fields are filled in etc. 
I am pretty sure the content of the code is right but there is an issue with the punctual side of the PHP! I looked on PHP manual and it seems to be right? I get an error of

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' on line 11 . 
>   Here is the code ( not all of the register script though)

```
<?php 
require('config/database.php');
require('includes/constants.php');
require('includes/functions.php');

//if form been submitted
if(isset($_POST['register'])) {

    //if all fields been filled in

    if(not_empty(['name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirm'])){       


    $errors = [];    
   .....(continued)

?>
```

This code works through localhost but doesn't work through web host? Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnConde Okay so really weird. I just ran this script how it is through localhost and it worked. But when I run it through web host it doesn't? I am not sure why this happened?

Comment: You're running different versions of PHP at each location

Comment: @JohnConde Of course! Thank you very helpful indeed! Is there anyway of knowing or changing the versions I am running on?

Comment: `phpinfo()` will tell you what version you're running but your production is clearly 5.3 or older and local is 5.4 or higher. You almost certainly can't change the PHP version on the host. Fortunately fixing this easy. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments your production host is running PHP 5.3 or older while your development environment is running PHP 5.4 or newer which is where the `[]` array syntax is added.

Fortunately just some minor tweaks will make this code run on PHP 5.3:

```
if(not_empty(array('name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirm'))){       

    $errors = array();
```

Comment: Wondering if OP does have a `not_empty()` custom function.

Comment: I'm assuming they do based on the fact that they say is was working and that code clearly would bomb out otherwise (and they also have a functions.php file where it could be hiding.

Comment: Yep. HowEver, seems like OP's ran off into the sunset.